# Data Views repository internally

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I'm trying to build an automation that runs daily to get the data from the data views email related and store them internally so I can query for more than 6 months easily when needed.

I have created separate DE for every table as _Sent, _Open, _Click, _Job etc. with all null fields but I'm not sure what would be the best way to set it up as if I use append I will just get duplicates and if I use update I need to use a PK and in my case I need all the data.

I'm thinking to use the a composite key composed on SubscriberKey and JobId and use append and check in the query if exists before appending but not sure if this is the best way to go.

Does anyone have a working mechanism to do this and what is the best way to set it up?

Comment: As you suggest yourself, you will need to use a compound key, however it will not be sufficient with only SubKey and JobID. There are multiple threads here on SFSE discussing this topic, eg. [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293331/primary-key-combination-for-click-data-view) and [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362754/select-from-sent-dataview-duplicate-value-error-occuring/362768#362768)

Comment: @LukasLunow Thanks!